# Webclient call returns entity ID with null value when the other part correctly

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices, webclient, java-11

I use WebClient to make calls between services by using Spring boot and Java 11. However, I receive the response entity with a null ID and the other parts have valid values. Whereas I have another call (WebClient) for another service and I receive the correct
response. How can I fix this issue in order to receive also the ID

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Customer {

    @JsonProperty("customer_id")
    private Integer customerID;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private Integer balance;
}
```

```
final String CUSTOMER_BASE_URL = "http://CUSTOMER-SERVICE/api/v1";

Customer customer = webClient.baseUrl(CUSTOMER_BASE_URL).build().get().uri("/customer/1")
                .retrieve().toEntity(Customer.class).block().getBody();
```

Response:

```
customerID = null
name = "Renos"
surname = "Bardis"
balance = {Integer@16157} 100
```